# Redisson Hibernate 2L cache setup but always executes SQL query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, redis, redisson

I'm trying to setup Redisson Hibernate 2L caching but I'm seeing the hibernate query execute every time even though the results are clearly cached on my Redis instance.

When debugging I can see it goes through hibernate and does the query execution and then after it goes into the `putIntoCache` from `RedissonStorage.java` as expected. When I check Redis I can see the new cached values. However, on a subsequent call to my service it again goes through the hibernate `executeQueryStatement` for the the exact same hibernate query but interestingly it then goes into the `getFromCache` from `RedissonStorage.java` and appears to return the value from Redis. Why is it executing the query every time and not actually checking redis first?

appliation.yml

```
spring.profiles.active: local

server:
  port: 9000

spring:
  config:
    active:
      on-profile: local
  cache:
    type: redis

  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    generate-ddl: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
        ddl-auto: create-drop
        show_sql: true
        cache:
          use_query_cache: true
          use_second_level_cache: true
          factory_class: org.redisson.hibernate.RedissonRegionFactory
          redisson:
            fallback: true
            config: redisson/redisson.yml
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    username: postgres
    password: admin
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    initialization-mode: always
```

redisson.yml

```
singleServerConfig:
  address: "redis://localhost:6379"
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.6.4'

    implementation 'org.redisson:redisson-hibernate-53:3.16.8'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    compileOnly 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1'
    compileOnly 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Entity class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Cacheable
@Cache(region = "employeeCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long employeeId;

    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeLastName;
}
```

```
@Component
public class EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeEntity findByEmployeeId(Long employeeId) {
        return employeeRepository.findByEmployeeId(employeeId);
    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {

    EmployeeEntity findByEmployeeId(Long employeeId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well looks like JPA caching will work for the default `findById` but will not work for `findAll` or a custom `findByType` or in this case `findByEmployeeId`.

However, I found a way to make it work by use of `@QueryHints`.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.QueryHint;

import static org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {

    @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "true")})
    EmployeeEntity findByEmployeeId(Long employeeId);

}
```